# How to Parse JSON Object/Array in Ajax

Tags: ajax, json, jsonp, arrays

How will I be able to get the value of updated in this json that is from my web service:

```
{"listener":{"id":"1","updated":"false"}}
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
$.ajax({
       ...
        success : function(data) {            
            console.log("received listener: " + data);            
            var received = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));                              
            var listener = received.listener;  
            var length = listener.length;
            //alert('returned json' + data + ' no. of products received: ' + length);
            console.log('returned json' + listener + ' no. of listener received: ' + length); //it says undefined for the length

            var updated = listener[0].updated;

        }
    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));` :o

Comment: Also, an Object does not have a length property. What is your bug, exactly?

Comment: I want to get the value of updated which is false.

Comment: I got it, like Hamish said. listener.updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, this line doesn't make sense:

```
var received = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
```

`JSON.stringify` converts a `JSON` structure to a string, and `JSON.parse` does the opposite. In other words:

```
var received = data.listener; // is equivalent.
```

Secondly, `received` is an *object*:

```
{"id":"1","updated":"false"}
```

It's not an array, so it does not have a `length` property. If you were looking to get the `id` of the `received` object then you'd obviously use:

```
var updated = listener.id;
```

For your code to work `data` would have to look like this:

```
{"listener":[{"id":"1","updated":"false"}]}
```